# Disable debugging page popping up in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

This might have very obvious solution but I'm afraid I cannot find out how to disable this specific page which pops up each single time I use the break command whilst debugging. Every time I have to close it because I don't need it; moreover, it pops up any next time I use the break command on the toolbar.

I'm using Visual Basic Express Edition 2010

How can this be disabled?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You can also enable .NET Framework source stepping, which will drop you into the appropriate section of the Framework code that's running. I'm not sure why this is better than the page you're seeing now, but it's worth pointing out as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use Debug + Break All.  It is typically useless anyway because it is pretty unlikely that you'll break your own code.  Which is what the window is telling you.  Set a breakpoint on a line of your own code, the code you want to debug or verify.  Clicking in the left margin will set one.

Comment: Sometimes I'd like to add some code during debugging at any given time, therefore I use the Break button. I'll go ahead with breakpoints.

Comment: It is rather unusual to decide to add code when you are *not* debugging it.  Just hit Stop instead of Break.

Comment: I might be wrong, but don't you mean it is unusual when *indeed* debugging it?

Comment: No, when you use Debug + Break All then you were not busy debugging.